# QGIS 2.14 - Saving Lat/Long csv file to ESRI Shapefile Error

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, qgis-processing

I have a csv file that I bring into QGIS 2.14 with standard lat and long formatting. The file displays fine but when I try to save it as an ESRI shapefile I get an error:

Export to vector file failed.

> Error: Feature write errors:
>   Feature creation error (OGR error: Error in psSHP->sHooks.FSeek() while writing object to .shp file.)

I have tried many other files including examples from various sites on the internet and get the same error. In other words, I cannot get this functionality to work at all and I do not think it is file specific.

**Note the below has been ruled out as a cause of the problem, but I am leaving it in for future reference:**
I will also note that when I try to start QGIS 2.14 Desktop I get an error as follows:

> Runtime Error!
>   Program: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Essen\bin\qgis-bin.exe
>   R6034
>   An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.

I suspect that is probably the problem although it hasn't affected any functionality up to this point.

Comment: Perhaps download again and reinstall, just g**gled for 'r6034 runtime error'.

Comment: Thanks! Actually one of my colleagues has resolved the runtime error now, but still same problem with failing to save a shapefile.

Comment: could you provide part of your csv to probably reproduce the issue?

Comment: ok, then off to g**gle again for 'OGR error: Error in psSHP->sHooks.FSeek()', wich gives me this: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3236. Is the shape per haps too big?

Comment: oops, this is 6 years old and long fixed...

Comment: but this https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13468 is possibly also related to big shapefiles

Comment: Do you have write permission on the target folder?

Comment: I have tried with multiple files. Definitely not too big. I am convinced it is a security issue. Nothing works that writes a shapefile.